# Run JUnit4-Tests parallel in Eclipse

Tags: junit, parallel-processing, junit4

maven-surefire-plugin enables running JUnit tests in parallel[1] - is there way to run JUnit-Tests in Eclipse in parallel, too?

[1] e.g.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

"Running tests in parallel" https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [tempus-fugit](http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/documentation/junit/parallel/) to run tests in parallel in Eclipse. This should work.

Comment: Worth to mention that the [tempus-fugit][1] Eclipse plugin **only** runs test methods in parallel per test class in sequential (like the above maven-surefire-plugin `parallel/methods` configuration), not test classes themselves in parallel (like the maven-surefire-plugin `parallel/classesAndMethods` configuration, eventually combined with the multi-module Maven parallel build).


  [1]: http://tempusfugitlibrary.org/documentation/junit/parallel/