# How to use tempus-fugit in eclipse to run junits in parallel without modifying the source code?

Tags: junit, parallel-processing

Based on the information in following link I am able to run junits in parallel from eclipse by adding `@RunWith(ConcurrentTestRunner.class)` to my test classes .

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13063715/825707

But I have a legacy code with around 400 junit test classes and around 4000 test cases. I don't want to update the 400 java files with `@RunWith(ConcurrentTestRunner.class)` , is there a way to create a suite or a change in plugin so that I am able to run all of them in parallel without modifying my source code ?

Thanks 
Shakti